# How to get current_active_user items in FastAPI from postgres database

Tags: python, fastapi

Using the FastAPI example on how to `get` the currently logged in user data, i ran into a problem where any user that logs in has access to the whole items in database.
I want to be able to just retrieve the items created by the current_active_user from my postgres database. I just modified the original code from the fastAPI docs. I tried to pass the response model in the route as a list using:

```
@app.get("users/me/items/", response_model=List[ShowProduct])
async def read_own_items(db: Session = Depends(get_db), current_user: Vendor = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    products = list_products(db=db, owner_id=current_user.id)
    if products.owner_id == current_user.id or current_user.is_superuser:
        list_products(db=db)
    return products
```

The show product model is this:

```
class ShowProduct(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: int
    owner_id: int

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

Now for the list_products function:

```
    products = db.query(Product).filter(Product.owner_id == id).all()
    return products
```

The error i get is **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'owner_id'**.

My database model shows the owner_id when i make a get all products call with postman or the swaggerDOCS to my databse :

```
    {
        "name": "Ofe Nsala",
        "price": 5000,
        "size": "1 Bowl",
        "owner_id": 1
     }
```

Here is my database model:

```
class ShowProduct(ProductBase):
    name: str
    price: int
    size: str
    owner_id: int

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

Please am i doing the app.get call to list my DB users wrong or what? can someone point me in the correct direction on how to make such calls.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend to do with `if products.owner_id` - this is what is generating your error - you get a list of products back from your `list_products` function, which you then try to access a `owner_id` property on. The `owner_id` property is present _on each product_, not on the list of products.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh. I am trying to replicate this route with a real DB and in my case postgres DB. From the fastAPI [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/):  `@app.get("/users/me/items/")
async def read_own_items(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_active_user)):
    return [{"item_id": "Foo", "owner": current_user.username}]` . So when a user access the endpoint, the products uploaded by the user gets shown.

Comment: It seems like you already filter for owner_id in your `list_products` function? (`.filter(Product.owner_id == id).all()` - but this should probably be `.filter(Product.owner_id == owner_id).all()`). If you filter inside that function, there is no need to manually try to filter anything in your view function.

Comment: Thanks Mats. Replacing owner_id with id now returns the logged in users products instead of the whole database products. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `id` in your `list_products` function - this is the internal `id` function and not the `owner_id`, since it seems like that's the name of the argument (since you didn't include the definition of the function I'm guessing from how you call the function):

```py
products = list_products(db=db, owner_id=current_user.id)
```

Modify the list_products function to use `owner_id` to filter the model instead:

```py
return db.query(Product).filter(Product.owner_id == owner_id).all()
```